# Why does using str.format create unicode errors?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I know that in Python 2 unicode errors are a mess, but what I don't understand is why `str.format` introduces them to an otherwise working situation. I was having trouble with some unicode characters, and testing out IDLE got me this:

```
>>> s = u'\xef'
>>> print s
ï
>>> print "%s" % s
ï
>>> print '' + s
ï
>>> print '{}'.format(s)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print '{}'.format(s)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems that `str.format` is the only example where this is an issue. I'm *guessing* that somehow the function is making a bad assumption about only being passed ascii suitable strings, but I'd like to know how I can handle this best as the results are erratic.

This only seems to happen when it's a unicode string, whether using the actual character or a code. Both alternatives as a plain string work fine:

```
>>> s = 'ï'
>>> print '{}'.format(s)
ï
>>> s = '\xef'
>>> print '{}'.format(s)
ï
>>> s = u'ï'
>>> print '{}'.format(s)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    print '{}'.format(s)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: It's not a "bad assumption" -- it's history. If you use the string types and methods from before good Unicode support was introduced, you'll get bad or no Unicode support. If you want good Unicode support, either use Python 3 or be very careful to always use the unicode types in Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you say

```
print '{}'.format(s)
```

the string you try to format with a unicode string is bytes (python2 str type).
This:

```
print u'{}'.format(s)
```

works ok.